Изменение конфигурации аудио-устройств через терминальные команды
Интересует, существует ли возможность внесения изменений в конфиги аудио-устройств без использования GUI. Конкретизирую: хотелось бы создать скрипт, что в автоматическом режиме переключал бы устройства ввода-вывода "по умолчанию", т.е. создавал бы пару rear-mic line-out, выполнял какие-то действия, переключался на следующую пару line-in line-out, еще группа действий, и последнее переключение front-mic headphone, с последней группой действий.
Ручное переключение через менеджер звукового драйвера (realtek), или же через любой другой микшер в данном случае неудобен, как и физическое включение/отключение портов.
Отдельный вопрос, но напрямую касающийся темы: возможно ли разделение звуковых потоков переднего и заднего выходов звука через терминальные команды/скрипты/консольные программы (если, конечно, это позволяет чипсет и кодек). То есть, опять же, разделение звука без обращения к GUI realtek.
Аналогичная задача для Unix решается банальной настройкой Alsa, но и такой терминализации, как в unix-подобных ОС в Windows, увы, нет. Потому и встал вопрос, возможно ли это вообще.
Я рассматриваю любые решения: от написания программ с использованием специализированных библиотек, до работы с реестром через управляющие файлы.

Ну тут искать нужный путь у WinAPI и оборачивать это в powershell.
